# Longer time to bring SQL online after node failover

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, failover

We had a strange issue post our regular OS patching for SQL servers.

Per best practices, we apply patch on Passive and do node failovers to make current passive, active and vice versa to complete patching.

Generally node failover is seamless and completes under a min. However recently we had issue where it took 4 minutes to bring SQL online after the node failover:

I am checking logs and events but could not find the reason: below is the findings so far:

Note: The SQL server is running on VM

1. No increased in SQL server activity
2. Databases are part of DB mirroring
3. No increase in user connections or user queries running longer in that duration
4. VLF under 500 for all databases
5. NO CPU/Memory pressure and LPIM is enabled.
6. The process which was seemed to killed time out long running during failover was EXEC sp_server_diagnostics 20 running for past 86745234 secs

Please assist what else should i be checking to find the root cause?

Edit- I tried analyzing the cluster log and can see sql offline was initiated but i am not sure where it spend atleast 4 mins internally to actually shut down sql and bring it back. after 4 mins sql error log had all enteries for databases being brought up approx 10 secs. So it looks DB might not hve any involvement here for slowing down process.

Edit- some VLF info when checked currently

[image]

Comment: Both many VLFS, and large VLFs, have caused slow failovers in my experience. Just because there are < 5000 doesn't mean they're small. Might be something else to look into.

Comment: @ErikDarling: I agree. I am cheeking the sizes of those VLFs as well. I am checking my best for that something else , just seem to be running out of ideas if something out of the blues just happened here

Comment: Is this an FCI or an AG? It sounds like you're describing an FCI, but it's not explicit. :)

Comment: Also--how much memory do you have on these servers?

Comment: @AMtwo: This is 2 node FCI and memory is 128 GB with 16 logical processors

Comment: @AMtwo: Batch req/sec is on avg 60-100 on this FCI inbstance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your problem is caused by the databases going through [recovery](https://am2.co/2019/10/recovery-of-database-is-0-complete-approximately-1000000-seconds-remain/) to redo or undo transactions that haven't been hardened to data files.

### Avoid recovery all together

Before doing **planned** server reboots or failovers of an FCI, *particularly one with a lot of memory*, I like to run a `CHECKPOINT` on every database. This minimizes the time spend on a clean shutdown of all databases, and (when databases aren't shut down cleanly) minimizes crash recovery time on restart.

I use `sp_ineachdb` from the [First Responder Kit](http://firstresponderkit.org/) to do this:

```
EXEC DBA.dbo.sp_ineachdb 'CHECKPOINT;`;
```

If you hate free code that makes your life easier, you could do something with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'CHECKPOINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '; '
FROM sys.databases;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql;
```

### But make recovery faster by doing less work

And of course, as [Erik, Darling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling) mentioned in the comments, make sure your VLFs are in order and properly sized. Scanning those VLFs during crash recovery is what can cause you all the pain you're seeing. For planned maintenance you can `CHECKPOINT` to minimize or eliminate crash recovery. But if you have... uhhh.... a crash and failover unexpectedly, that crash recovery is still going to happen, and there's not much you can do about it.

### Be less direct

I've also had tons of luck with [indirect checkpoints](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/05/system-configuration/0-to-60-switching-to-indirect-checkpoints). We've rolled this out across our entire environment to much success.

### And lobby the powers that be for an upgrade

SQL Server 2019 includes a feature called [Accelerated Database Recovery](https://am2.co/2019/10/what-the-heck-is-accelerated-database-recovery/), which can speed up recovery process, particularly when there are long-running, large transactions. ADR is not just for recovery after a crash, but also helps in other scenarios where the transaction log needs to be recovered–including Availability Group secondary redo and Failover Cluster Instance failovers.

Comment: Andy- Thanks for great explanation. I totally agree and will check on those points. Its just this has happened for first time with this app. Its always under a min so wandering if something strange happened. Few errors from  cluster log that i see are RSH call deadlock monitor timing out and other message which says failed to stop service with error 1460

Comment: The "failed to stop service" errors indicate that shutdown took a long time (possibly due to checkpoints, but it could be something else). It's very possible that the instance shutdown didn't complete cleanly, or it just took a very long time. In fact, my answer is in the context of *startup* being slow, but it sounds like it could be *shutdown* was slow. The above feedback still stands, though!

Comment: @Amtwo- Just had a quick question , when above of your solutions we were discussing. Instead of running checkpoint ( which many believed will need a downtime) when running before node failover and we dont know how much time it will take for TB size of databases, could running log backup job on the instance will do? i read books online that log backup also kick off checkpoint

Comment: Checkpoints do not require downtime. SQL Server will do checkpoints lazily in the background normally. Explicitly running a checkpoint is no different and requires no downtime.

Comment: @AMtwo- Thank you. Also do you think log backup can run as an alternative to checkpoint. Its ok if you want me to post that as separate question